# AngularJS : Factory undefined inside Controller Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

When I call a factory method within the controller it's fine- but when I call a factory method within a controller method it's undefined.

Here's my factory:

```
app.factory('config', ['$http', '$interval', function($http, $interval, $scope) {
    return {
        lines: function() {
            return $http({
                url: appPath+'/config.php?data=lines',
                method: 'JSON'
            })
        },
        updateLines: function() {
            $http.post(appPath+'/write.php?handler=update line', $scope.lines).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    return true;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    return false;
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller('lineController', function($scope, $interval, $http, config) {
    // this works fine
    config.lines().success(function(data) {
        $scope.lines=data;
    });

    this.addToLine = function(line, customer) {

    };

    this.unassign = function(customer, line) {
        var index = line.indexOf(customer);
        line.splice(index, 1);

        // Cannot read property 'lines' of undefined
        config.updateLines();
    };
});
```

Inside the controller scope my factory config is defined, however when referencing config in a method the factory is undefined. AngularJs is new to me, so if this is bad practice then I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Did you include the file with this factory in the app? This factory is in the same module?

Comment: Yes they are in the same module.

Comment: Are you getting any exception at the console?

Comment: No, I get "Cannot read property 'lines' of undefined" in the console. The factory works fine when I call it outside of a method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are getting appears to be correct. `$scope.lines` does not exist in your factory but in your controller. So what you might have intended to do would be to pass that value in from the controller to the factory like the below

function in controller

```
config.updateLines($scope.lines);
```

function in factory

```
updateLines: function(lines) {
    $http.post(appPath+'/write.php?handler=update line', lines).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return true;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `$scope` should *only* be injected into controllers. The way to think about it is `services` and `factories` are for your data, `controllers` and `$scope` are for your UI. The controller's job is to orchestrate data living on the `$scope` and do interesting things with it, such as passing it to services.